# Adding default accounts with ETH in populus?

Tags: solidity, populus

I'm thumbing through populus docs, and I don't see anything about adding additional default accounts preloaded with ETH into the test chain?

I see I can set defaultAccount and/or web3.eth.coinbase, but I'm not seeing where I can make up arbitrary accounts to be populated into the test chain.